# How do I keep the iteration order of a List when using Collections.toMap() on a stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am creating a `Map` from a `List` as follows:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc");

Map<String, Integer> map = strings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length));
```

I want to keep the same iteration order as was in the `List`. How can I create a `LinkedHashMap` using the `Collectors.toMap()` methods?

Comment: please check my answer below. It is only 4 lines of code using a custom `Supplier`, `Accumulator` and `Combiner` for the `collect` method of your `stream` :)

Comment: The question has already been answered, I just want to lay out the path to finding answer to this question.(1) You want order in map, you have to use LinkedHashMap (2) Collectors.toMap() has many implementations, one of which asks for a Map. So use a LinkedHashMap where it expects Map.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The [2-parameter version of `Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) uses a `HashMap`:

```
public static <T, K, U> Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, 
    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) 
{
    return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);
}
```

To use the [4-parameter version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)), you can replace:

```
Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length)
```

with:

```
Collectors.toMap(
    Function.identity(), 
    String::length, 
    (u, v) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
    }, 
    LinkedHashMap::new
)
```

Or to make it a bit cleaner, write a new `toLinkedMap()` method and use that:

```
public class MoreCollectors
{
    public static <T, K, U> Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toLinkedMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper)
    {
        return Collectors.toMap(
            keyMapper,
            valueMapper, 
            (u, v) -> {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
            },
            LinkedHashMap::new
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why such complexity? you can easily do that, check my answer below

Comment: `mergeFunction` that in 4-parameter version `Collectors.toMap()` has no clue about which key is being merged, both `u` and `v` are the values. So the message about IllegalStateException is not that right.

Comment: @hzitoun because if you simply use `Map::put`, you end up with (possibly) different values for the same key. By using `Map::put`, you indirectly chose that the first value you come across is incorrect. Is that what the end-user wants? Are you sure? If yes, then sure, use `Map::put`. Otherwise, you aren't sure and can't decide: let the user know that their stream mapped to two identical keys with different values. I would have commented on your own answer, but it's currently locked.

Answer (score 96):

Make your own `Supplier`, `Accumulator` and `Combiner`:

```java
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc"); 
// or since java 9 List.of("a", "bb", "ccc");
    
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> mapInOrder = myList
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                          LinkedHashMap::new,                           // Supplier LinkedHashMap to keep the order
                          (map, item) -> map.put(item, item.length()),  // Accumulator
                          Map::putAll);                                 // Combiner

System.out.println(mapInOrder);  // prints {a=1, bb=2, ccc=3}
```

Comment: @Sushil Accepted answer allows to reuse logic

Comment: Do you know what is faster? Using your version or the accepted answer?

Comment: @Nikolas  can you please explain what you mean with **side effects**? I actually have the problem to decide which one to choose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479650/stream-map-with-collectors-tomap-vs-accumulator?noredirect=1#comment108755306_61479650

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, what side-effects? It's an accumulator. `java.util.stream.Collectors#uniqKeysMapAccumulator` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The right solution for this problem is

Current ----> 2 parameter version

`Map<Integer, String> mapping = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Entity::getName));`

Right ----> Use 4-parameter version of the Collectors.toMap to tell supplier to supply a new LinkedHashMap:

`Map<Integer, String> mapping = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Entity::getName, (u, v) -> u, LinkedHashMap::new));`

This will help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function to map array of objects by some field:

```
public static <T, E> Map<E, T> toLinkedHashMap(List<T> list, Function<T, E> someFunction) {
    return list.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   someFunction, 
                   myObject -> myObject, 
                   (key1, key2) -> key1, 
                   LinkedHashMap::new)
               );
}


Map<String, MyObject> myObjectsByIdMap1 = toLinkedHashMap(
                listOfMyObjects, 
                MyObject::getSomeStringField()
);

Map<Integer, MyObject> myObjectsByIdMap2 = toLinkedHashMap(
                listOfMyObjects, 
                MyObject::getSomeIntegerField()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, [`toMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html) is order-preserving.

> ```
> fun <K, V> Iterable<Pair<K, V>>.toMap(): Map<K, V>
> ```
>
> Returns a new map containing all key-value pairs from the given collection of pairs.
>
> The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original collection. If any of two pairs would have the same key the last one gets added to the map.

Here's its implementation:

```
public fun <K, V> Iterable<Pair<K, V>>.toMap(): Map<K, V> {
    if (this is Collection) {
        return when (size) {
            0 -> emptyMap()
            1 -> mapOf(if (this is List) this[0] else iterator().next())
            else -> toMap(LinkedHashMap<K, V>(mapCapacity(size)))
        }
    }
    return toMap(LinkedHashMap<K, V>()).optimizeReadOnlyMap()
}
```

The usage is simply:

```
val strings = listOf("a", "bb", "ccc")
val map = strings.map { it to it.length }.toMap()
```

The underlying collection for `map` is a `LinkedHashMap` (which is insertion-ordered).

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 9* you can collect a *list of [map entries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-)* with the same order as in the original list:

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc");

List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = strings.stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e, e.length()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(entries); // [a=1, bb=2, ccc=3]
```

Or you can collect a *list of [maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-)* with a single entry in the same way:

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc");

List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = strings.stream()
        .map(e -> Map.of(e, e.length()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(maps); // [{a=1}, {bb=2}, {ccc=3}]
```