# How to filter a map by its values in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map where the values are strings and the keys are lists:

```
Map<String, List<BoMLine>> materials
```

I'd like to filter this map by its values; something like this:

```
materials.entrySet().stream()
       .filter(a -> a.getValue().stream()
           .filter(l -> MaterialDao.findMaterialByName(l.getMaterial()).ispresent)
```

But it's not working for me. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If I understand your filtering criteria correctly, you want to check if the filtered `Stream` you produced from the value `List` has any elements, and if so, pass the corresponding `Map` entry to the output `Map`.

```
Map<String, List<BoMLine>>
    filtered = materials.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(a->a.getValue()
                                    .stream()
                                    .anyMatch(l->MaterialDao.findMaterialByName(l.getMaterial())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(),e->e.getValue()));
```

This is assuming `MaterialDao.findMaterialByName(l.getMaterial())` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: I am not sure about my solution and it is not working when i want to collect it to map "e" is not a map it is just an object

Comment: @nazila `e` is a `Map.Entry<String,List<BoMLine>>`. I did make some silly syntax errors in the call to `collect`. See edited answer.

Comment: You don't need to use `filter()`, just pass the predicate as an argument to `anyMatch()`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks. I answered from memory without checking the API. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Eran I tried to filter using the same but when I do have a null value in one of the objects it throws a null pointer exception. How I can avoid that?

Comment: If you need to keep iteration ordering (`LinkedHashSet`), see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096750/411282

Answer (score 49):

Generally, this is how you can filter a map by its values:

```
static <K, V> Map<K, V> filterByValue(Map<K, V> map, Predicate<V> predicate) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> originalMap = new HashMap<>();
originalMap.put("One", 1);
originalMap.put("Two", 2);
originalMap.put("Three", 3);

Map<String, Integer> filteredMap = filterByValue(originalMap, value -> value == 2);

Map<String, Integer> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
expectedMap.put("Two", 2);

assertEquals(expectedMap, filteredMap);
```

Comment: In case someone is wondering, `Entry::getKey` & `Entry::getValue` in above snippet actually refers to `java.util.Map.Entry::getKey` (need to `import java.util.Map` or `java.util.Map.Entry` for it)

Answer (score 11):

All the previous answers provide a solution that creates a new `Map`. This may be inefficient if you want to remove just a few entries.

The following removes the elements from the *existing* `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("One", 1);
myMap.put("Two", 2);
myMap.put("Three", 3);

myMap.keySet().removeAll(
        myMap.entrySet().stream()
           .filter(a->a.getValue().equals(2))
                   .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

System.out.println(myMap);
```

Prints:

```
{One=1, Three=3}
```

How does it work? It collects all *keys* that need to be removed into a temporary `List`, then removes them from the original `Map` in one go. A temporary `List` is required because modifying a `Map` invalidates streams and iterators. However, building a new `Map` is potentially a much more costly operation that building a `List`.

If you want to remove a lot of entries (50% or more), then it's better to build a new `Map` indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I finally made it work. My second filter was completely useless. The answer is like this:

```
Map<String, List<BoMLine>>
filtered = materials.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(a -> a
                      .getValue()
                       .stream()
                        .allMatch(
                            b -> MaterialDao.findMaterialByName(
                                    b.getMaterial()).isPresent()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()))
```

Comment: If you don’t need the source map afterwards and it’s mutable, consider performing the operation inplace: `materials.values().removeIf(a -> !a.stream().allMatch(b -> MaterialDao.findMaterialByName(b.getMaterial()).isPresent()))`

Comment: I wish there was a simple non-parametrized `Collectors.toMap()` to just create the exact input map again

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, one of the most concise java 8 code may look like this :

```
public Map<String, ReportPlaceholderValue> getAllPlaceholders() {
    Map<String, ReportPlaceholderValue> result = chamberDetailsPlaceHolders;

    result.entrySet().stream().filter( e -> !(e.getValue() instanceof StringReportPlaceholderValue) )
       .map( Map.Entry::getKey )
       .collect( Collectors.toList() ).forEach( result.keySet()::remove );

    return result;
}
```