# Use stream to filter certain key-value pairs in hashmap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a hashmap1 with the signature
Map<String, List<**Self-Defined-Object**>>

The key/value set within hashmap1 is:

```
key = ".ABC", value = [Self-defined Object1, Self-defined Object2]
key = ".DEF", value = [Self-defined Object3, Self-defined Object4]
key = ".GHI", value = [Self-defined Object5, Self-defined Object6]
```

Stream operation is performed for hashmap1:

```
hashmap1.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> { ...//performing some operation})
```

**What I want to do:** I want to filter out the key value pair with key = ".ABC" before doing `forEach`.

**What did I do**: I added `.filter(item -> item.getKey().equals(".ABC")` after the `.stream` operation and before the `.forEach` operation.

**What is wrong:**
After the filter, it skips to the end of the forEach (meaning forEach is not being run), I suppose after filtering, the size of hashmap becomes 0, which means I am not getting the key value pair I need.

I tried switching `equals` with `startsWith`, but it's still the same.

I am not exactly sure what is wrong with my current way of filtering the key.

Comment: And without the filter you get all entries?

Comment: Map contains unique key. So why are you filtering key? directly get the map.get(ABC).
If you want to filter the values then can use the filter in such way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459961/how-to-filter-a-map-by-its-values-in-java-8

Comment: For information, the issue is not reproductible on my side. I'm pretty sure you're missing to share an important information about the keys of your map.

Comment: Please create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Code works as expected for me.

Comment: add a `.peek(item -> System.out.println(item.getKey()))` (or use a logger instead of sysout if you prefer) after your filter.  Also, as Saima pointed out above, `Map.get` will be much simpler and faster.

Comment: thank you. I need to get the key-value pair within the stream operation, since there'll be some important logic performed in the `forEach` stream operation`.forEach( e -> {//some important logic}`, therefore I plan to use filter before the `forEach` operation instead of using `map.get`

Comment: There is nothing you can place in a `forEach` that you can’t place after a simple `get` call. So just place your “important logic” after the `get`.

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.filter(Predicate)` does the opposite of what you think it does; it's *inclusive*, not *exclusive*. Here's the description:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.

So if you want to "filter out" a specific entry from the map stream, you would use a "not equals" predicate, like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Collection<Number>> source = Map.of(
            ".ABC", List.of(1,2,3),
            ".DEF", List.of(4,5,6),
            ".GHI", List.of(7,8,9)
            );

    source.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> !".ABC".equals(entry.getKey()))
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry));
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
.GHI=[7, 8, 9]
.DEF=[4, 5, 6]
```

---

A slight variation for the `.filter(...)` call if you statically import `Predicate.not`:

```java
      .filter(not(entry -> ".ABC".equals(entry.getKey())))
```