# filter Map in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I was trying to filter Entries in HashMap using Streams API, but stuck in last method call `Collectors.toMap`. So, I don't have clue to implemement **toMap** method

```
    public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
            HashMap<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = studentsMap.entrySet().stream().
            filter(s -> s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("delhi")).
            collect(Collectors.toMap(k , v));
    }

public class Student {

        private int id;

        private String firstName;

        private String lastName;

        private String address;
    ...

    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Just so you're clear. Each parameter in Collectors.toMap takes a Function, so k and v don't exist. It would be `toMap(s -> s.getKey(), s -> s.getValue())` which can be converted to Method References as in the answer by @Eran. Which I recommend even if they are a little longer

Comment: you might want to read this question and the one it is marked a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just generate the output `Map` out of the key and value of the entries that pass your filter:

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
    Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
        studentsMap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("delhi"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: Do i  need to cast result Map to `HashMap<Integer,Student>`?

Comment: @Ankit Are you asking whether the result would be a HashMap, or are you asking how to make sure the result is a HashMap? The 2 argument variant of `Collectors.toMap` returns a `Map`. There are other variants in which you can specify the type of Map you want created.

Comment: @Ankit You want to use the simplest Interface that that is necessary. It shouldn't matter if it's a HashMap (which it will be), but if you need a specific implementation like LinkedHashMap, then you need to use the 4 param toMap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090277/streams-collections-tomap-from-list-how-to-keep-the-order

Comment: @Eran: I was getting Compilation error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to HashMap<Integer,Student>`. Now, after casting things are working. Thanks

Comment: @Ankit Don't take the result by HashMap<Integer, Student>, take it by Map<Integer, Student>. You don't need any casts then.