# Apply multiple filter to a map in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, filtering, predicate

Based on the following question: [filter Map in Java 8 Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328544/filter-map-in-java-8-streams)

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
    Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
        studentsMap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("delhi"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

This filter students leaving in `dehli`. How could I filter students leaving in `dehli`, `amsterdam` or `new york`?

Is there a better way than filtering three times the original map and merging the three outputs together?

Comment: The part after the `->` can by any Java expression that you want. So write an arbitrarily complex statement that checks if the address is any of the desired values and returns `true` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`Predicate#or(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or(java.util.function.Predicate)) to logically compose two `Predicate`s.

```
Predicate<Student> livesInDelhi = student -> "delhi".equalsIgnoreCase(student.getAddress());
Predicate<Student> livesInAmsterdam = student -> "amsterdam".equalsIgnoreCase(student.getAddress());
Predicate<Student> livesInNewYork = student -> "new york".equalsIgnoreCase(student.getAddress());

Predicate<Student> livesInAnyOfTheseThreeCities = livesInDelhi.or(livesInAmsterdam).or(livesInNewYork);
```

A `filter` call would look like

```
.filter(e -> livesInAnyOfTheseThreeCities.test(e.getValue()))
```

> How could I adapt the fourth lines where you're chaining filtering parameters?

Assuming we have an array of cities

```
final String[] cities = {"delhi", "amsterdam", "new york"};
```

for each `Student`, we could write a `Predicate<Student>` and reduce them by `Predicate::or`

```
Predicate<Student> livesInAnyOfGivenCities = 
  Arrays.stream(cities)
    .map(city -> (Predicate<Student>) student -> city.equalsIgnoreCase(student.getAddress()))
    .reduce(Predicate::or)
    .orElseGet(() -> student -> false);
```

`student -> false` is used when there are no cities given.

Comment: @Naman your assumption is also nice, it would reduce repetitive `student.getAddress()` calls. However, I wanted to emphasise the transition from a `Student` to a `boolean` (not `String->boolean` because I believe `address` should be more complex than a `String`)

Comment: In you example you have three predicates, but let's assume I don't know how many I would have (like I receive an array of cities, sometimes with x cities, sometimes with y). How could I adapt the fourth lines where you're chaining filtering parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you should use plain old object oriented programming here and create a separate method with meaningful name:

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
    studentsMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(s -> s.getValue().liveIn("delhi", "amsterdam", "new york"))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Of course this requires creating a corresponding method in `Student` class, but why else do we need objects and OOP?)

```
public class Student {

   // other methods of Student

   public boolean liveIn(String... cities) {
     return Arrays.stream(cities).anyMatch(this.city::equals);
   }
}
```

Array is just for example - you can use set, list or whatever you want. 
The point here is to create a meaningful methods that could be used in stream api.

Comment: “plain old object oriented programming” would be `Arrays.asList(cities).contains(city)` instead of `Arrays.stream(cities).anyMatch(this.city::equals)`

Answer (score 1):

Use one filter with multiple conditions:

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
    Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
        studentsMap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("delhi") ||
                                s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("amsterdam") ||
                                s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("new york"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Or you can simplify with a `Set`:

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
    Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
        studentsMap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(s -> Set.of("delhi","amsterdam","new york").contains(s.getValue().getAddress().toLowerCase()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
List<String> toFilter = Arrays.asList("delhi", "amsterdam", "new york");
Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap =
        studentsMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> toFilter.stream().anyMatch(f -> s.getValue().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(f)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Like with other similar answers, [this approach is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903213/apply-multiple-filter-to-a-map-in-java/57903284#comment102227286_57903397) and [using `List` as well as unnecessarily creating new strings is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903213/apply-multiple-filter-to-a-map-in-java/57903284#comment102231035_57903397)…

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one too, if you are unsure, how much of the cities could come in the filter condition  in near future..

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
final List<String> includedCities = List.of("DELHI", "NEW YORK", "AMSTERDEM", "SOME MORE");

Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
    studentsMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(s -> includedCities.contains(s.toUpperCase()))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

**UPDATE (after comments by @JoachimSauer):**

This should be much finer..

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
final List<String> includedCities = List.of("DELHI", "NEW YORK", "AMSTERDEM", "SOME MORE");

Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
    studentsMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(s -> exclusiveCities.stream().anyMatch(s::equalsIgnoreCase))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

**UPDATE (after comments by @Holger):**

Even Better..

```
public void filterStudents(Map<Integer, Student> studentsMap){
final Set<String> includedCities = new TreeSet<>(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
Collections.addAll( includedCities , "DELHI", "NEW YORK", "AMSTERDEM", "SOME MORE");

Map<Integer, Student> filteredStudentsMap = 
    studentsMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(includedCities::contains))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: Just make sure your code [never runs in Turkey](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/): `"delhi".toUpperCase().equals("DELHI")` will evaluate to `false` in any Turkish locale, because `"delhi".toUpperCase()` will return `"DELHİ"` (yes, that's a capital-I with a dot on top of it). Don't use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` when you really want to do `equalsIgnoreCase()`!

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks.. I wasn't aware of this. :)

Comment: The better solution would be `Set<String> excludedCities=new TreeSet<>(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER ); Collections.addAll(excludedCities, "DELHI", "NEW YORK", "AMSTERDEM", "SOME MORE");`, followed by using `.filter(exclusiveCities::contains)` in the stream. That’s avoiding the the problem @JoachimSauer mentioned, as well as the creation of new strings via `toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase` and the linear search through a `List`. In other words, is more efficient.

Comment: Yup. I had thought abt using `Set` instead of `List` as data-structure after posting the answer. But never thought of this. This is the reason why I love StackOverflow. Thanks @Holger. :)

Comment: Just noticed that `excludedCities` should actually be named `includedCities`…

Comment: Updated.. but it wasn't `excludedCities` initially, it was `exclusiveCities`.. got messed up in some frequent edits.