# Multiple group by java stream collecting to hashMap

Tags: java, java-stream, groupingby

I'm have the following objects:

```
 List<CartItem> cartItemsList = cart.getItems().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(f -> f.getProduct().getPrice()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

 Map<Product, Map<Customization, List<CartItem>>> map =cartItemsList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CartItem::getProduct,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(CartItem::getCustomizations)));
```

My issue is about map: because I need to preserve order, defined in the first list(cartItemsList) , map isn't a good solution. Have I to use linkedHashMap(or any other solution) to preserve order and how do that?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090277/how-do-i-keep-the-iteration-order-of-a-list-when-using-collections-tomap-on-a

Comment: If you need a `Map` that preserves elements in insertion order, then yes, `LinkedHashMap` is a good choice.

Comment: Yes, `Collectors.groupingBy` has an overloaded version with [`Supplier<Map>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) parameter

Comment: @Madlemon maybe..how apply this example to my scenario?

Comment: e.g. `.collect(LinkedHashMap::new,(map, cartItem) -> map.put(cartItem.getProduct(), cartItem.getCustomizations()), Map::putAll);`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-), the `Supplier<Map>` goes after classifier.

```java
 Map<Product, Map<Customization, List<CartItem>>> map = cartItemsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        CartItem::getProduct, 
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(CartItem::getCustomizations)
));
```

If the nested map needs to be `LinkedHashMap` too, the following code should be used:

```java
Map<Product, Map<Customization, List<CartItem>>> map = cartItemsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        CartItem::getProduct, 
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            CartItem::getCustomizations,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.toList()
        )
));
```

---

For `Collectors.toMap` it is also possible to provide specific Map using [4-argument overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-), where `Supplier<Map>` goes last argument.